# How to port `error_messages_for` from Ruby erb to Java JSP/JSTL?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, jsp, jstl, erb

How would you port this front-end logic from erb to jsp/jstl?

```
<%= error_messages_for :foo %>
```

Is there any Java library that does something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain them in a `Map<String, String>` in the business code, put it in the request scope like so:

```
Map<String, String> messages = new HashMap<String, String>();
request.setAttribute("messages", messages);
// ...
messages.put("foo", "Please enter valid value");
```

Then you can access it in JSP the usual EL way by `${messages.key}` or `${messages['key']}`:

```
<input id="foo" name="foo" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.foo)}">
<label for="foo" class="error">${messages.foo}</label>
```

EL is builtin in JSP since ages. You don't need to install it. Only the `fn:escapeXml` (which is mandatory to prevent XSS) is part of JSTL which may need to be installed separately at certain servletcontainers.

Comment: So the <label for="foo"> won't be seen unless there is an error? What triggers it to be seen?

Comment: Just ... If there's no content, then nothing is visible to enduser :)